# Как задать динамическое имя php

Tags: php

Делаю что-то типа двойного цикла и нужно сделать динамическое название переменной.
Хочу получить что-то типа `$v++[]`, но переменную для массива нельзя цифрами называть.
Хотел еще сделать `$name = array('Ania', 'Petia', 'Vasia');` а потом вызвать как `$name[0][1]`
Подскажите как правильно сделать, а то я уже в край запутался. Спасибо

UPD: Вопрос снят

Comment: А чем вас не устраивает `$v[][] = ['text'];` ? А потом пробегаться `$v[$i++][$j++]` или через `foreach`

Comment: @ArchDemon, да, это работает. Спасибо большое :)